# How can i find thd implementation details in Android Developers Doc?

Tags: android, material-components-android, android-bottomsheetdialog

When i view others Android code, i find a class which extends `BottomSheetDialogFragment`. I want to use it (`BottomSheetDialogFragment`), then I find it need to add implementation in `build.gradle(app)`. I had viewed this website [`BottomSheetDialogFragment` in official Doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomsheet/BottomSheetBehavior). But I can not found any implementation details about `BottomSheetDialogFragment`. I finally found implementation in other tutorial by Google. I want to konw how can find the implementation details in Official Doc.

Comment: The `BottomSheetDialogFragment` is part of the material components library: https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `BottomSheetDialogFragment` is provided by the Material Components Library:

- [Official Doc](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/BottomSheetDialogFragment.md)
- [Source code](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/tree/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/bottomsheet)
- [Demo code](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/tree/master/catalog/java/io/material/catalog/bottomsheet)

Relevant part of the doc about the usage:

- Subclass `BottomSheetDialogFragment`
- Override the `onCreateView` method.
- Use one of the two versions of `show` to display the dialog. Notice `BottomSheetDialogFragment` is a subclass of `AppCompatFragment`, which means you need to use `Activity.getSupportFragmentManager()`.

Note: Don't call `setOnCancelListener` or `setOnDismissListener` on a `BottomSheetDialogFragment`, instead you can override `onCancel(DialogInterface)` or `onDismiss(DialogInterface)` if necessary.